# How do I find this JQuery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text" class="the_name" data-num="1" value="Choose a Font.">
```

Find all elements that have "input.the_name" **AND** data-num = 1. How do I do both of those attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
$('input.the_name[data-num="1"]')
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.the_name[data-num="1"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('input.the_name[data-num="1"]')`